Install magento 2.4.6-p6 using docker
I am new to docker setup. I have install the docker desktop application on my windows system. Now I want to install magento 2.4.6-p6. It should be this version only not the new one.

Follow this link : https://ecommerce.folio3.com/blog/magento-2-docker-setup-guide/

I strongly advise using a service like Warden. Warden is a very simple to use local environment tool that bootstraps docker - it comes with simple Magento configuration steps also.
Follow the steps here to get up and running with whatever version of Magento you wish: https://docs.warden.dev/environments/magento2.html

I would recommend Mark Shust's docker-magento project on Git. I've been using it for several months. Works like a charm. My next step is to try to install it on a VPS. If any of you have done that please message me or comment below. https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
